# Type Mismatch error while opening a text

Tags: vbscript

I have 5 log(.log) files in the Test folder.

For the first file the loop is working fine but for the second file I am getting

> Type Mismatch error in "Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile (vPath,1)" line.

I don't know what is problem?

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFol = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Test\")
For Each objFile In oFol.Files
  vPath = objFile.Path
  Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile (vPath,1)
  msgbox oFile.Readline
  oFile.Close
  Set oFile = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: Just i wonder what's your purpose to do like that ? Did you want to read just the first line for each file in this folder ?

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want do .. Real code is different and I found the problme. It's resolved now

Comment: in this case share your solution